# Converting NetCDF files to geo-referenced GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I have a NetCDF .nc file that gives me an initial error `Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute` from `gdalinfo`.

After searching I found out this relates to NetCDF files having no inherent CRS. Whats the best way to add a CRS, e.g. `EPSG:4326`, etc.? I've seen the `rioxarray` package mentioned but I had some trouble with the `to_raster` function.

Here is the data:

```
$ gdalinfo Flood.nc
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: Flood.nc
Size is 512, 512
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Pressure
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[155x155] Pressure (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Radar
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[155x155] Radar (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Rain6h
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[155x155] Rain6h (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":RainTot
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[155x155] RainTot (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":RH
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[155x155] RH (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":U
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[155x155] U (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":V
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=[155x155] V (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_8_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Latitude
  SUBDATASET_8_DESC=[155x155] Latitude (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_9_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Longitude
  SUBDATASET_9_DESC=[155x155] Longitude (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_10_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Terrain
  SUBDATASET_10_DESC=[155x155] Terrain (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_11_NAME=NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Landuse
  SUBDATASET_11_DESC=[155x155] Landuse (32-bit floating-point)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Here is what I've tried:

1. Convert the "Pressure" subdataset

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff NETCDF:"Flood.nc":Pressure test_pressure.tif
```

2. Change CRS to EPSG:4326

```
gdal_edit.py -a_srs EPSG:4326 test_pressure.tif
```

I'm new to working with this kind of data so I'm wondering if there is a better/more efficient way of doing this?

If it helps here is the file as an `xarray.Dataset`:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (NX: 155, NY: 155)
Dimensions without coordinates: NX, NY
Data variables:
    X          (NX) float32 ...
    Y          (NY) float32 ...
    Pressure   (NY, NX) float32 ...
    Radar      (NY, NX) float32 ...
    Rain6h     (NY, NX) float32 ...
    RainTot    (NY, NX) float32 ...
    RH         (NY, NX) float32 ...
    U          (NY, NX) float32 ...
    V          (NY, NX) float32 ...
    Latitude   (NY, NX) float32 ...
    Longitude  (NY, NX) float32 ...
    Terrain    (NY, NX) float32 ...
    Landuse    (NY, NX) float32 ...
```

**UPDATE**:

Here is some example data. I used the `xarray` package to convert the `Dataset` into a `dataframe`.

```
         X         Y     Pressure  Radar  Rain6h  RainTot  ...         U         V   Latitude   Longitude  Terrain  Landuse
NX NY                                                      ...
0  0   0.0       0.0  1015.783508  -20.0     0.0      0.0  ...  2.894194 -0.131631  33.019382 -133.426315      0.0     17.0
   1   0.0    9000.0  1015.769226  -20.0     0.0      0.0  ...  2.387919 -0.092172  33.099922 -133.433914      0.0     17.0
   2   0.0   18000.0  1015.757568  -20.0     0.0      0.0  ...  1.781186 -0.000224  33.180466 -133.441544      0.0     17.0
   3   0.0   27000.0  1015.749756  -20.0     0.0      0.0  ...  1.024312  0.068302  33.261024 -133.449173      0.0     17.0
   4   0.0   36000.0  1015.748901  -20.0     0.0      0.0  ...  0.201696  0.096872  33.341579 -133.456818      0.0     17.0
   5   0.0   45000.0  1015.753967  -20.0     0.0      0.0  ... -0.603568  0.075843  33.422153 -133.464493      0.0     17.0
```

**UPDATE 2:** `rioxarray` attempt and results. The input NetCDF file can be found [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13876811042857410156).

`xds` is an `xarray.Dataset` object

I tried to use the `to_raster` function and got an error:

```
xds.rio.set_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
xds["Pressure"].rio.to_raster(test.tiff)
```

Error: `DimensionError: x dimension not found. 'set_spatial_dims()' can address this. Data variable: pressure`

So I tried that next. I used multiple variables as the 'x' and 'y' parameters to `set_spatial_dims()` but the `NY` and `NX` combo were the only ones that didnt error:

```
xds.rio.set_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
xds.rio.set_spatial_dims("NY", "NX", inplace=True)
xds["Pressure"].rio.to_raster(test.tiff)
```

This still gave me the same error as above.

I believe this might have something to do with the dimensions not having coordinates:

```
Dimensions:    (NX: 155, NY: 155)
Dimensions without coordinates: NX, NY
```

Comment: Is the result correct? You do not need to run gdal_edit.py command separately, you can add  `-a_srs EPSG:4326` into your gdal_translate command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I loaded the result GeoTiff file into QGIS and it looked correct, although it was black and white. Should I worry about that warning `Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute`, before processing? Also the GDAL docs has this note about the `NetCDF` driver:

"This driver is intended only for importing remote sensing and geospatial datasets in form of raster images. If you want explore all data contained in NetCDF file you should use another tools.". Should I use another method to avoid any issues with using GDAL?

Comment: Result may be OK if the georeferencing is correct and if the only band that you have has pixel values which represent the pressure correctly. What I know about NetCDF is mostly that it feels odd.

Comment: I think each column is a band. I can create a separate question to try and understand this data but it looks like there are other types of values. I believe `U` and `V` are wind arrows. I'm trying to visualize this in the most appropriate way.

Comment: I tried opening this in QGIS and applying OpenStreetMap tiles and it looks like the conversion to `EPSG:4326` didnt work. Are there any other methods I could try?

Comment: I would recommend asking this here with any errors you ran into using rioxarray: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/discussions

Comment: Or update your question with the rioxarray errors here. If you could share a link to your dataset, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: @snowman2 I made an `Update 2` at the bottom of the post. I linked the input file and added the results of my `rioxarray` attempt.

Answer (score 2):

This is a work in progress and is untested, but here is what you need to do:

1. Rename the dimensions/coordinates of x/y so they are the same.

```py
xds = xds.rename_dims({"NX": "x", "NY": "y"}).rename_vars({"X": "x", "Y": "y"}).set_coords(["x", "y"])
```

2. Write the CRS to the file.

```py
xds.rio.write_crs("<WKT or EPSG Code>", inplace=True)
```

3. Write to Tiff

```py
xds["Pressure"].rio.to_raster("test.tif")
```

Comment: I got this error: `ValueError: Cannot rename NX to longitude because longitude already exists. Try using swap_dims instead.`

Looks like the dimensions have to be named `x` and `y` so I tried renaming to this: `.rename_dims({"NX": "x", "NY": "y"})`

Then after running `xds["Pressure"].rio.to_raster("test.tif")` I got this error:  


NotGeoreferencedWarning: The given matrix is equal to Affine.identity or its flipped counterpart. GDAL may ignore this matrix and save no geotransform without raising an error. This behavior is somewhat driver-specific.
  **kwargs)

Comment: The dim and the coords for x,y need to have the same name. I made the rename dims part first to see if that would help.

Comment: I get this now: `ValuError: IndexVariable objecs must be 1-dimensional`.

Comment: Ah, that means that your data is projected and the X and Y coordinates are the ones to use. It also means you need to figure out what the projection is for your dataset.

Comment: I'm using data that was created by someone else so I'm not sure what the projection is. If I did figure it out, what would I need to do so this conversion to GeoTIFF can work?

Comment: I updated the example for when you find the correct CRS of the data.

Comment: Thanks @snowman2! I'm able to run that code but when I add one of the sub-datasets to QGIS nothing shows up and a `Zoom to Layer` takes me to Africa. This dataset shows rainfall for southern California. I'll try to find the right CRS and try it again.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/661#issuecomment-717346011

Comment: This will also likely be helpful: https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/#correct-crs

Comment: Thanks I'll check these out!

Answer (score 0):

I check your data and open it using Panoply, and located at west coast. If you know the bounding box <top_left_lon> <top_left_lat> <bottom_right_lon> <bottom_right_lat>, then will much easier to convert using gdal_tarnslate.

`gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr <top_left_lon> <top_left_lat> <bottom_right_lon> <bottom_right_lat> -a_srs EPSG:4326 input.nc output.tif`

[image]